# Modifying Existing Eclipse Plugin and Correctly Installing it

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded the source code for the EMF based UML2 Plugin and changed a class in the org.eclipse.uml2.uml.edit project to remove special characters when returning string representations. Now when I export the projects and place the jar files either in the dropins directory or replace my current uml2 plugin jar files in plugins directory, The UML files are no longer recognized, in short my modified plugin does not install correctly (no error is thrown and I can see the files being picked up under Plugins->Target Platform) .

However, When I run the plugin as an eclipse application (from the workspace) I can see the changes I made being reflected in the new instance of eclipse.

What can I do to ensure that the plugin installs correctly?

Is there a documented procedure of how to build the uml2 plugin (or any comparable plugin) after modification?

Answer (score 0):

Select the project and open the context menu. There is an entry `PDE` near the bottom of the menu. In there, you can find an entry to build the plugin for deployment. This gives you the features and plugins directory with the fixed files. Copy both into your Eclipse install.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the UML2 plugins require some kind of magic build script, exporting the one plugin you changed and overwriting the original in your Eclipse installation should be the easiest solution. One potential problem which comes to mind is conflicting plugin version numbers: make sure you don't have two identical versions of your modified plugin in your Eclipse installation.

When debugging plugins which apparently don't work properly at runtime, I always look at *Help > About Eclipse Platform > Configuration Details*. This lists all the plugins found by Equinox during startup, along with their status (see the Javadoc of the org.osgi.framework.Bundle interface for explanation).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem as you describe here . I dont have any answer to your problem but i am sharing what worked for me .

I created a local update site of the plugin on my system. [Create update site for your plug-in](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#p2deployplugin)  article explains very very nicely the steps needed to accomplish this .